# How to develop inspect element tab for my Web Browser(Using VS2015 Community) in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, visual-studio-2015, inspect-element

How to Develop inspect element tab section for my Web Browser which i've developed in VS2015 Community. Please help I'm searching this from last few days...

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "inspect element tab" ?  Can you explain what you are trying to do in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion for this could be using the [*TreeView Class*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) which could potentially provide you with what you are looking for (If you're looking to create the '*Inspect Element*' in it's entirety). If you just want the code then simply using the *DocumentText* *WebBrowser* *Property* would do that. Just having a *TextBox* and writing the document text into it, then you could make changes and then on a '*onFocus*' Event on the *WebBrowser* you could have it write the edited text back to the browsers html code.

(I have done the second way before out of curiosity and it's obviously much simpler than the other way that i have suggested)

-
But with the *TreeView* :

You can dynamically add [*Nodes*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodes(v=vs.110).aspx) to that object.
*Roots* are 'Base' Nodes (Parents) and the and the *Child*, well, is obviously the *Child* of the *Root Node*.
(A node consisting of an actual name to call it by, a display name (text), and a tag for any extra info.)

---

But anyways, the *TreeView* would be the most work to do.

---

A few other things potentially worth your time to look at, if you chose to do either option, I've written below in a comment.

Comment: I few more Links:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec6f754a-7433-4272-b0a3-9a48797867a6/iv-some-questions-about-web-browser-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298458/inspect-element-using-system-windows-forms-webbrowser

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932097/vb-net-webbrowser-html-of-documenttext-is-inaccurate-compared-to-inspecting-el

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333973/how-to-get-rendered-html-processed-by-javascript-in-webbrowser-control